# Compare two variables inside Go template

Tags: html, loops, go, go-templates

In the data I pass to my template I have the two variables `Type` and `Res.Type` I want to compare to preselect an option for my select field.

To illustrate my problem I have created this simplified version:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "html/template"
    "log"
)

type Result struct{ Type string }

func main() {
    types := map[string]string{
        "FindAllString":      "FindAllString",
        "FindString":         "FindString",
        "FindStringSubmatch": "FindStringSubmatch",
    }
    res := &Result{Type: "findAllString"}

    templateString := `
    <select name="type">
        {{ range $key,$value := .Types }}
            {{ if eq $key .Res.Type }}
                <option value="{{$key}}" selected>{{$value}}</option>
            {{ else }}
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>
            {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </select>`
    t, err := template.New("index").Parse(templateString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var b bytes.Buffer
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(&b)
    err = t.Execute(writer, struct {
        Types map[string]string
        Res   *Result
    }{types, res})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    writer.Flush()
    log.Println(b.String())
}
```

It should select the `"FindAllString"` option but it only generates the error

```
panic: template: index:4:21: executing "index" at <.Res.Type>: can't evaluate field Res in type string

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x53f6e0, 0xc4200144c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.main()
    /home/tobias/ngo/src/github.com/gamingcoder/tmp/main.go:41 +0x523
exit status 2
```

When I just compare two normal strings it works but I want to know if there is an idomatic way to do this. I have seen that you could add a function to the template but I feel that there must be a simpler way for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the `{{range}}` action changes (sets) the dot (`.`) even if you use loop variables (`$key` and `$value`) in your case. Inside a `{{range}}` the dot is set to the current element.

And inside `{{range}}` you write:

```
{{ if eq $key .Res.Type }}
```

Since values in your loop are `string` values, `.Res.Type` is an error, because there is no `Res` field or method of a `string` value (the current element denoted by the dot `.`).

Use the `$` sign to not refer to the loop value, but to the param passed to the template execution:

```
{{ if eq $key $.Res.Type }}
```

This will work, but won't give you the desired output, as you have a typo:

```
res := &Result{Type: "findAllString"}
```

Use capital letter in `Result` as your `types` map also contains values with capital letter:

```
res := &Result{Type: "FindAllString"}
```

With this you get the desired output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZtZAoeOtF3)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 
    <select name="type">
                <option value="FindAllString" selected>FindAllString</option>
                <option value="FindString">FindString</option>
                <option value="FindStringSubmatch">FindStringSubmatch</option>
    </select>
```

Also note that you could simply write the loop like this:

```
{{range $key, $value := .Types}}
    <option value="{{$key}}"{{if eq $key $.Res.Type}} selected{{end}}>{{.}}</option>
{{end}}
```

Also note that for testing purposes you may simply pass `os.Stdout` as the writer for template execution, and you'll see the result on your console without having to create and use a buffer, e.g.:

```
err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, struct {
    Types map[string]string
    Res   *Result
}{types, res})
```

Try the simplified version on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pEvOsU-bNS).

Read this answer for more insights: [golang template engine pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines/42508255#42508255)