# get helm values from yaml inside a range loop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I get `.Values.someVal` from `values.yaml` file or passed through cli inside a `{{ range .Values.smtg }}` loop?

for eg.

```
spec:
      containers:
      {{ range $k, $v := .Values.smtg }}
      - name: {{ $k }}
        image: {{ printf "%s:%s" (required "no img" $v) (required "no tag" .Values.someVal) | quote }}   <<<--- how can I get .Values.someVal from values.yaml or cli? 
      {{- end }}
```

If I try to get them with `.Values.smtg` I will got : `... at <.Values.someVal>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}`

Comment: ... simple https://stackoverflow.com/a/55257763/3610959 use $.Values.someVal

Answer (score 6):

Use `$.Values.someVal`. The `$` will always point to the root context:

```
spec:
  containers:
  {{ range $k, $v := $.Values.smtg }}
  - name: {{ $k }}
    image: {{ printf "%s:%s" (required "no img" $v) (required "no tag" $.Values.someVal) | quote }} 
  {{- end }}
```