# Difference between {{template "base" }} and {{template "base" .}} in go-gin

Tags: templates, go, go-gin

What is the difference between `{{template "base" }}` and `{{template "base" .}}`?

I use go-gin, both can run with no problem. I cannot find any description in the documentation about this.

Comment: For explanation of the concept and answer to your question, see [golang template engine pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines/42508255#42508255).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [godoc text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template):

> `{{template "name"}}`
>       The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.
>
> `{{template "name" pipeline}}`
>       The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
>       to the value of the pipeline.

So `{{template "base"}}` calls the template `base` with no data in the context (globals are still available, of course), and `{{template "base" .}}` calls it with whatever data is in-scope at the point of the call.