# How to access struct field value in a map of that struct with a specific key

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I have "FormError" struct. I pass this struct to my template. So how to access InputError struct field value with specific key in the template?

```
type InputError struct {
    Val string
    Has bool
}

type FormError struct {
    Errs map[string]InputError
}
```

This doesn't work.

```
<input name="Name" type="text" value="{{index .Errs.Val `Name`}}">
```

Comment: Maybe this discussion bring a little bit more of light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{{.Errs.Name.Val}}`.  There's no need to use index.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/0B2C1tMqsO)

Answer (score 2):

`Errs.Val` isn't valid, you need to separate the lookup and field access:

```
{{ $myval := index .Errs "key" }} {{ $myval.Val }}
```

Or if you only need to use the value once:

```
{{ (index .Errs "key").Val }}
```