# How is this invocation called?

Tags: go, pipeline, hugo, go-templates

Inside Hugo templates, I'm aware that you can call a function using `function param`:

```
{{ singularize "cats" }}
```

but in the documentation, I'm also seeing you can also do:

```
{{ "cats" | singularize }}
```

I've never encountered this way of calling functions (inside languages like Ruby/Python). Is this Go-specific, or just Hugo-specific? How is this way of calling a function called? Also, can you do it if you have more than 1 type of argument?

Comment: Hugo uses Go's standard template library, which is well-documented: https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

Comment: The above is mentioned in the first sentence of the first section of Hugo's own template docs: https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/

Comment: Actually, there is a similar feature in Django templates called filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a feature of the Go template engine, although it's not a new idea, if you used unix systems, you can do the same in shell commands (think of e.g. `ls |more`).

It's called "chaining": you specify a sequence of commands, and the output of each is used as the input of the next in the chain.

It's documented at [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> A pipeline may be "chained" by separating a sequence of commands with pipeline characters '|'. In a chained pipeline, the result of each command is passed as the last argument of the following command. The output of the final command in the pipeline is the value of the pipeline.

The Go template engine only allows you to register and call functions and methods with a single return value; or 2 return values of which the second must be of type `error` (which is checked to tell if the call is considered successful, and non-`nil` errors terminate the template execution with an error). So you can't chain commands that have multiple return values, and you can't specify tuples to pass multiple values to functions having multiple parameters.

For more about pipelines, see [golang template engine pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines/42508255#42508255)