# Why don't HTML templates that I have parsed work?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-html-template

I parsed my template files to make it easier for me to work.

I named them `{{define "pagearea"}}`.
For example `{{define "footer"}}`.

### Folder layout

- **footer.tmpl** - footer area
- **index.tmpl** - my home page
- **main.go** - go code :)
- **topheader.tmpl** - part of top html

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "html/template"
)

type Home struct {
    Sitelang string
    Sitetitle string
    Sitename         string
    Siteslogan string
}

func main() {
    homeTmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("./topheader.tmpl", "./footer.tmpl",  "./index.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Home page parsing error:", err)
    }

    data := Home{Sitelang: "en",
        Sitetitle: "Home - Render Test",
        Sitename        : "test 1",
        Siteslogan: "mmmmeeeeeuaawww!"}
        homeTmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)

}
```

#### footer.tmpl:

```
{{define "footer"}}
<footer>

    <small>
        This is footer area. Test.</small>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

#### index.tmpl:

```
{{template "topheader"}}

<h1>
        Main area</h1>

{{template "footer"}}
```

#### topheader.tmpl:

```
{{define "topheader"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="
        {{.Sitelang}}">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>
        {{.Sitetitle}}</title>

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1>
            {{.Sitename}}
    </h1>
    <p>
            {{.Siteslogan}}
    </p>
</header>


{{end}}
```

Build command: `go build .`

I really don't know what I'm missing. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) to parse the template files. This will parse all files, and return a template that will "contain" all parsed templates as associated templates. The returned [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) will represent the **first** template. Quoting from `template.ParseFiles()`:

> The returned template's name will have the (base) name and (parsed) contents of the first file.

Then you use [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) which executes the template whose method you're calling. So in your case that will be `topheader.tmpl`, but that template does not generate any output, that template just *defines* a template: `{{define "topheader"}}`.

Most likely you want to execute the `index.tmpl`, so use [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate) where you can identify the executable template by its name (and don't forget to check the returned error):

```
err = homeTmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.tmpl", data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("index template execution failed:", err)
}
```

Another mistake is that when your `index.html` template includes (executes) other templates using the `{{template}}` action, you don't pass any parameter to them, yet you want to use the initial parameters.

So pass the current params when invoking other templates. Your `index.html` should be:

```
{{template "topheader" .}}

<h1>
        Main area</h1>

{{template "footer" .}}
```

See related questions:

[Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671)

[Golang template engine pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines/42508255#42508255)

Comment: It does not place variables in templates. For example `<p> </p>` True: `<p>mmmmeeeeeuaawww!</p>`

Comment: @SeanTolstoyevski Fixed that issue too, see edited answer.

Comment: Now everything is great. I'm new to SO. Do I need to delete my comments.

Comment: @SeanTolstoyevski It's up to you. If they serve no purpose now, you may. And if the post answers your question, consider upvoting and accepting it.